# Any reason a Python loop would stop iterating (without throwing errors) before finishing all list elements?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm writing a Python program which sees if all the letters of a user-inputted word are found in other words in a list. So, for instance, if the user inputs "memphis," the program should print a list of words (such as "euphemism," "membership," "mimeographs") which contain all of the same letters.

```
wordList = ["blah", "blah", "blah"]
userWord = input("Enter a word to compare: ")

userLetters = list(userWord)    #Converting user-inputted string to list of chars

matches = []         #Empty list for words that might match later.

for word in wordList:
    mismatchCount = 0          #Setting/resetting count of clashes between words
    wordLetters = list(word)   #Converting word of comparison into list of chars

    for letter in userLetters:
        if letter in wordLetters:
            userLetters.remove(letter)   #Removing already-matched letters
            wordLetters.remove(letter)   #Removing already-matched letters
        else:   
            mismatchCount += 1

    if mismatchCount > 0:       
        continue                    #Mismatch--abandons word and moves to next
    matches.append(word)    #If word fails the above IF, it gets added to matches

print(matches)
```

Problem is that none of the words in the big list of words are failing the test. Even words that should fail get appended to the list of matches. So when I enter "memphis" to compare against the big list, every word in the list gets printed.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you supposed to be modifying `userLetters` inside the loop?

Comment: Never modify a list you are iterating over http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/

Comment: It would be easier to do `userLetters = set(userWord)`, then `matches = [word for word in wordList if userLetters.issubset(word)]`.  This does the same job, but with only two lines of code.

Comment: Strings are already iterable, `>>> 'a' in 'abcd'` equals `True`. Also, you should check the `all` function, it seems well-suited for your particular problem: `matches = [word for word in wordList if all(c in word for c in userWord)]`

Comment: This is all very helpful, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any reason a Python loop would stop iterating (without throwing
>   errors) before finishing all list elements?

NO, but in your particular example, you are changing the size of the iterable`userLetters.remove(letter)` while iterating through it `for letter in userLetters:`

In Python, the behavior is well defined and you would end up skipping elements while iterating.

Alternatively, you should create a copy of the iterable you are iterating `for letter in userLetters[:]:`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So far that seems to be fixing the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove items from a list you are walking over. Make copies of the lists, e.g. using `[:]`:

```
...
for letter in userLetters[:]:
    if letter in wordLetters:
...
```

Comment: `if letter in wordLetters[:]`? Any reason to create a copy while comparing ? How would that be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it as

```
filter(set(userWord).issubset, wordList)
```

Example:

```
>>> filter(set("23").issubset, ["foo", "3foo2"])
['3foo2']
```